# gtsummary: multiple continuous variables as columns and than stratify by two categorial variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to summarize three continuous variable by one categorical variable.
Here is some dummy data  :

```
    test <-
  data.frame(
    score_1= sample(c("low","medium","high"),50, replace = T),
    land=rnorm(50,5,1),
    water=rnorm(50,300,1),
    fire=rnorm(50,3,1)
  )
```

I can easily stratify the data by tertile:

```
table<- test %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=score_1,
    statistic = all_continuous()~  "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) %>% 
  print()
```

Which will make this table:

[image]

However I need to transpose this table: the continuous variables need to be the columns.
The reason for that is that I actually have two more score to add, so data is actually looks like this:

```
test2 <-
  data.frame(
    score_1= sample(c("low","medium","high"),50, replace = T),
    score_2= sample(c("low","medium","high"),50, replace = T),
    score_3= sample(c("low","medium","high"),50, replace = T),
    land=rnorm(50,5,1),
    water=rnorm(50,300,1),
    fire=rnorm(50,3,1)
  )
```

I thought of creating three tables, one for each score (with the continuous variables as columns), and then merging the three using tbl_stack. But I don't know how to make the first table (and if that even possible with gtsummary).
Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the next release of gtsummary (v.1.5.0) the package will have a function designed to create tables just like the one you're requesting. While that new function is being vetted, you can use a similar (but not as easy to use) function from the bstfun package (on GitHub). bstfun is a package where some gtsummary functions are born, and when they mature they are migrated to gtsummary. Example code below!

```r
# remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun")
library(gtsummary)

test <-
  data.frame(
    score_1= sample(c("low","medium","high"),50, replace = T),
    land=rnorm(50,5,1),
    water=rnorm(50,300,1),
    fire=rnorm(50,3,1),
    all_one = 1L
  )

df_pvalues <-
  c("land", "water", "fire") %>% 
  purrr::imap_dfc(
    ~aov(
      formula = glue::glue("{.x} ~ score_1") %>% as.formula(),
      data = test
    ) %>%
      broom::tidy() %>%
      dplyr::slice(1) %>%
      dplyr::select(p.value) %>%
      dplyr::mutate_all(style_pvalue) %>%
      setNames(glue::glue("stat_1_{.y}"))
  ) %>%
  mutate(label = "ANOVA p-value")
df_pvalues
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   stat_1_1 stat_1_2 stat_1_3 label        
#>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>        
#> 1 0.12     0.6      >0.9     ANOVA p-value


tbl <-
  c("land", "water", "fire") %>%
  purrr::map(
    ~test %>%
      bstfun::tbl_2way_summary(score_1, all_one, con = all_of(.x),
                               statistic = "{mean} ({sd})") %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ paste0("**", .x, "**"))
  ) %>%
  tbl_merge() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>% 
      dplyr::bind_rows(df_pvalues)
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Daniel! it was a bit confusing for me but I think I got it.
Is there's a way to add statistic test as a row below? I tried "add_p" but obviously, that didn't work out.

Comment: what values do you want compared in the p-value? Any difference in mean by score_1, and the final table would have 3 p-values in a new row?

Comment: Yes exactly, another option that cross my mind is adding significance stars.

Comment: Wow, Thanks so much, it is extremely helpful and teachable for me (and hopefully for others).